# Bootstrapping semi annual bond

Tags: bond, yield-curve, bootstrapping

I have a bond that pays out semi-annually.
The coupon is 0.14, which means it pays 0.7 after 6 months, and then 100.7 after another 6 months. I need to find the discount factors by bootstrapping. Is the following approach corect:
ZC1= 0.07
And, $100= \frac{0.07}{1} + \frac{100.07}{(1+z)^2}$, where z is the zero coupon rate for 1 year.
Now my question is: should the discount factor for a year be $\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}$ or $\frac{1}{(1+z/2)^2}$

I'm new to finance, apologise if the doubt is too easy

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I guess you mean coupon rate is 14%? which means it pays 7 after 6 months and then 107 after another 6 months?
then your formula should be
100 = 7/(1+z/2)+ 107/(1+z/2)^2
this gives you the Yield to Maturity, assuming the current bond price is at par(i.e. 100)

Comment: for calculating discount factor would i use z or z/2?

Comment: also for say 1.5 years, will i use z or z/2?

Comment: It depends on the convention you're are using to calculate the discount factor (and therefore on how you will use it later on). If you want to use an annualized discount rate I suggest you use $1/(1 + z)^{j/n}$ for the $j$-coupon, where $n$ represents the number of payments a year.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{(1+z/2)^2}$ is the correct answer here. Because it is semi-annual you divide the rate by two and multiply the exponent by two for each period.

To answer your follow up question yes you will divide 1.5 by two but, to be clear, this would not be the first cash flow payment in your stream of payments. There would be 0.5 and 1 preceding this cash flow. All periods in semi-annual are divided by two and the exponent is multiplied by two.

For example, the last cash flow of a 30 year 5% fixed bond would be $\frac{1 + {(.05/2)}}{(1+ {z/2})^{2 * 30}}$

To use an explicit example, if you start the period at 0.45 years then the follow period will need to be 0.95 years, 1.45 years, 1.95 years and so on. You need the consistency of equally spaced periods in order for the semi-annual compounding to work.

FYI QuantLib has some built-in libraries that can help with building curves.

Hope this helps.